# Why some Notifications.userInfo is nil?

Tags: swift, observers

An example:
Why this Notification "didActivateApplicationNotification"

```
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                    selector: #selector(updateOnFocus(notification:)),
                    name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification,
                    object:nil)
```

Pass Through Notification an User Info Dictionary -> Code below = Returned Notification

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x60000191e3d0 {name = NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification; object = <NSWorkspace: 0x6000015443d0>; userInfo = {
    NSWorkspaceApplicationKey = "<NSRunningApplication: 0x60000394a800 (com.apple.ActivityMonitor - 6940) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x2aa2aa}>";
}}
```

And this Notification "activeSpaceDidChangeNotification"

```
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(updateOnSpaceChange(notification:)),
                   name: NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification,
                   object: nil)
```

Does not Pass an userInfo Dictionary through notification? -> Code below = Returned Notification

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x60000191e160 {name = NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification; object = <NSWorkspace: 0x6000015443d0>}
```

How can I padronize this notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "why" and no, you can't change this. These notifications come from the runtime. Some kinds of notification come with extra info in the `userInfo`, others don't. The way it works is the way it works. The end.

This is all perfectly well documented. The `didActivate` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1535049-didactivateapplicationnotificati) says:

> The notification object is the shared NSWorkspace instance. The userInfo dictionary contains the `applicationUserInfoKey` key with a corresponding instance of NSRunningApplication that represents the affected app.

So there's your user info. But the `activeSpace` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527073-activespacedidchangenotification) says:

> The notification doesn’t contain a `userInfo` dictionary.

There you go.